# Alamofire Response Property List

Tags: xcode, swift, alamofire, property-list

I'm going through a tutorial and am attempting to make an `alamofire` request to a property list. In the closure for the response property list, I use the arguments `(_, _, result)`. However, XCode gives me the error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(_, _, _) -> Void' to expected argument
>   type 'Response -> Void'

I am using `alamofire 3.0` beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alamofire right now is in version 3.3 according to the releases in the repository, since the version 3.0 it has change a little.

In you use the [**Response Handler**](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#response-handler) your closure need to look like this:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
     .response { request, response, data, error in
         print(request)
         print(response)
         print(data)
         print(error)
      }
```

And if you use for example the [**Response JSON Handler**](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#response-json-handler) everything is encapsulated now in the `response` like in this code:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
     .responseJSON { response in
         print(response.request)  // original URL request
         print(response.response) // URL response
         print(response.data)     // server data
         print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

         if let JSON = response.result.value {
             print("JSON: \(JSON)")
         }
     }
```

Or you can use this code for more easily handling:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
     .responseJSON { response in
         switch(response.result) {
         case .Success(let value):
            if let JSON = value {
              print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
         case .Failure(let error):
            print(error.description)    
         }
     }
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me, if doesn't work for you, paste your code to inspect problem please.

```
var params : Dictionary<String,String> = ["key":"value"]
Alamofire.request(.POST, "someURL" ,parameters: params).responseJSON()
{
    response in

    let data = JSON(response.result.value!)

    if(data != nil)
    {
        var status = data["status"] as? String
    }
}
```